# Libgdx TiledMap

Tags: position, libgdx

Hope you have a nice day. But i dont because i have a problem and i dont know how to resolve it. It makes me tired and bored so any helps will be appreciated.
I'm doing the collision detected in tiledmap Libgdx 0.9.8 version. After load a map:

```
    tiledMap = TiledLoader.createMap(Gdx.files.internal("map/lv1.tmx"));
    tileAtlas = new TileAtlas(tiledMap, Gdx.files.internal("map"));
    renderer = new TileMapRenderer(tiledMap, tileAtlas, 32, 32);
    camera =  new OrthographicCamera();
```

I try to add a character into the map and make him move:

```
    player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("data/man_test.png")));
    player.setSize(25, 35);
    player.setPosition(width/2, player.getHeight());        
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(player);
```

In Player class,I use parameter speed=120 and when I put the key down,the character will move up,down,left or right. When move right or up,velocity>0 and when move down or left,velocity<0. And I set position for character:

```
    setX(getX() + velocity.x * deltaTime);
    setY(getY() + velocity.y * deltaTime);
```

I try to get the row and the column of the character in map which is loaded by the code below:

```
    row = tiledMap.height -1 -(int) ((player.getY()) / tiledMap.tileHeight);
    col = (int) (player.getX() / tiledMap.tileWidth);
    // return the value of tile which has TileProperty equals to "noPass"
    collision = tiledMap.getTileProperty(noPassLayer.tiles[row][col], "noPass");
    if("1".equals(collision)){
        Gdx.app.log("Collision", "dectected");
    }
    Gdx.app.log("Row", ""+row);
```

I want to check the tile which character is standing on. But something wrong happened.For example,I opened the map by Tiled Editor and saw that the tile which I want to set collision with character was [181][13]. But when the character move to that tile, the row is not 181 but 191!!!.Btw,the column is exact. I dont know what happened.
I'm the newbie so I really need your helps.
Thank you so much!

Comment: It is inverted. You have two different coordinate systems. The tiled Editor starts counting from the left to the right and up to down. Inside of your game you regulary count upwards so left to right and down to up. That should it be. Had the same issue.

Comment: I resolved my problems. I downloaded the nightly build of libgdx,not the 0.9.8 version and all the problem were resolved!!!. I think that libgdx is a developing framework so there're some issues that users can have.
Hope that useful. Just download the nightly build and feel the beat.:D